# Calling Cloud Function with ParseReact

Tags: parse-cloud-code, parse-react

With `ParseReact`, it is possible to call Parse Query in a reactive way. I try to call user defined function from Parse Cloud Code but I don't see how to do. So do you have example about calling a cloud function in `ParseReact`

Comment: I don't think you can do it (at least with the current code base). Cloud Functions (run method) haven't been converted to be an Observable type. You should probably treat your cloud function request like you would a normal http request.

Comment: It would be a great enhancement